# Using Spring-retry with Dropwizard

Tags: dropwizard, spring-retry

Is it possible to make use of spring-retry within dropwizard? Or, for that sake, is there something like spring-retry in dropwizard?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of wha spring retry does, but for client retries, you can configure `retries` for `HttpClient`

```
httpClient:
  timeout: 500ms
  retries: 3
```

The number of times to retry failed requests. Requests are only retried if they throw an exception other than `InterruptedIOException`, `UnknownHostException`, `ConnectException`, or `SSLException`.

See [Dropwizard documenation](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.7.1/docs/manual/configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

From [Spring Batch - Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/index.html), [9. Retry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/retry.html):

> The retry functionality was pulled out of Spring Batch as of 2.2.0. It is now part of a new library, Spring Retry.

[Spring Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) can be used independently of other Spring projects.

e.g. In a Maven project you can simply add the following in your POM:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```